# Many transactions fail because of the current design of Read-Write set in Fabric

Tags: transactions, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

This is the doc for the Read-Write set semantics , http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readwrite.html, that means if multiple transactions write the value for a key in the same block, only the first one will pass the validation and be valid.

I have done some testing by using java sdk , the chain code I used is github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go/chaincode_example02, I initialized the chaincode as:
instantiateProposalRequest.setArgs(new String[] {"a", "300", "b", "200" )});
And then I sent out 3 transactions(each transaction will move 10 from a to b) continuously by using for loop and made them in the same block. After the block has been persisted by the peers, I query the value of b is 210 instead of 230, and I checked the ValidationCode of those three transactions, only the first one is 0 which means successful, all the others are 11. This result exactly matches with the doc.

But the value will be changed for the same key many times in one block is a very normal case. For example, there is a application for charity， all the people will transfer the money to the single account of the charity organization and the tps is very high, it will be a problem.

In the end of the doc , it mentions about **Transactions with multiple read-write sets are not yet supported.** Who can explain it in more detail? Can it solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I have only unverified assumptions about what multiple read-write sets shall be, so that part I leave open.

On the other hand, I think the problem is that example02 does not emphasize enough that Hyperledger is not a distributed database - it's a distributed *ledger*. If you want to implement a cryptocurrency with Hyperledger, why not follow e.g. the Bitcoin-established UTXO model? In this case you track the "unspent transactions owned by an account" directly, instead of the current account balance. The current account balance can still be computed e.g. in a query operation as a "ledger state view", if you will.

Incidentally, my impression is that the vast majority of use cases where Hyperledger will be able to shine won't be "cryptocurrency-like". (Rather asset management, "real" contracts, government, ...)

And if I may make a suggestion: such conceptual questions may have a better place on the fabric mailing lists and the various channels on RocketChat.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and suggestion. The reason I raise this question is as the following, 1. Many companies from financial world join our hyperledger project, including fintech company,investment bank and commercial company. The most of apps in these organizations are related to  asset management, just as mentioned by you "cryptocurrency-like". 2. Fabric has so many fancy features all the people want, the other kind of blockchain systems are far from the demands in reality. 3. We believe fabric will be more and more powerful :)